# How to set default image before upload using Croppie library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-file-upload, croppie

I'm using [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) to crop and upload images. Everything works fine except I can't set default image before uploading. I would appreciate if anyone helps:

Here is my javascript code:

```
function demoUpload() {
        var $uploadCrop;

        function readFile(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
                    $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                        url: e.target.result
                    }).then(function(){
                        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                    });

                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
            }
        }

        $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                type: 'rawcanvas'
            },

        });




        $('#upload').on('change', function () { readFile(this); });

        $('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
                type: 'canvas',
                size: 'viewport'
            }).then(function (resp) {
                popupResult({
                    src: resp
                });


  $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
        url: resp
    });




                // $('.cr-image').attr('src',resp).removeAttr('style');
                 //$('.cr-image').attr('style','width:300px');
                 //$('.cr-image').attr('aria-valuenow','0.1563');


                $('.image_cropped').val(resp);


                //$('#upload-demo').html('<img src="'+resp+'">');

            });
        });
    }
```

Demo image:

[image]

I googled a lot but could not find solution. Croppie documentation did not work for me either. :( Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation there is no option to set a default image. So the workaround I found is to set a default image on load and replace it when user uploads an image.

```
var isDefaultImage = true;
var logo = "/content/img/missing-image.jpg";

function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        partnerLogo.croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
        });
        $('#upload-container').addClass('ready');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

partnerLogoCropper = $('#upload-container').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 250,
        height: 150,
        type: 'square'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    },
    url: logo
 });

$('#upload').on('change', function () {
    readFile(this);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    // checking if it is the default image and user hasn't uploaded any new image
    if (!$('#upload-container').hasClass('ready') && isDefaultImage){
        alert("NOT UPLOADED AND DEFAULT IMAGE IS LOADED");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if u display only image than You can set background image.

Comment: This is not what I need. You did not get me properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add src to your image tag in html
Example :

```
<img src="/default_img.jpg"/>
```

or you can also add it through JQuery
Example :

```
$("#pic1").attr("src", "/image_path/default_img.jpg");
```

When you add/upload new cropped image through javaScript it will replace your default image.

Comment: It does not work. I knew that, tried but did not work on this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({

        url:'anonymous.png'

        viewport: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            type: 'rawcanvas'
        },

    });
```

add url:'anonymous.png' to select default image

Comment: Hi, welcome to the stackoverflow. Please don't forget to add some explanation when you answer a question.